# Interop.Excel wants to connect to Internet

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I'm making a simple C# application which read data from many excel files, process them and writes to another excel file. Problem is, when i start it, program is trying to make outbound connection to some IP address. After a little research, i found that it tries to do this when i declare an Excel.Application object. My code looks like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace MyProg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

When i run it, if i have network enabled, program tries to connect to external IP for about 5 seconds, then exits. If network is disabled, it exits instantly.
Anyone can explain this? IP don't belong to some kind of Microsoft server, and virus presence is ruled out...
Also, the same situation is with Word.Application object.

Answer (score 1):

I ran [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and then launched Excel to see what it called. It made calls to

- roaming.officeapps.live.com
- docs.live.net
- store.office.com

Unless you're extremely paranoid I wouldn't worry. It's checking for updates or perhaps to see if you're signed in to some cloud service. (When you automate Excel or Word with Interop you're starting an instance of the application.)

Comment: Well, my Excel didn't make any of this calls. I tried to resolve IP - it belong to some home Internet provider, not to Microsoft. Also, it makes it when i declare xlApp, not when i start Excel by writing  xlApp = new Excel.Application();
I'm not paranoid - just curious. I wasn't aware of this call until my boss told me about it.